# Perl $! vs $@ builtin variables

Tags: perl

A trivial question regarding Perl's built-in error indicators **$!** and **$@**. How they differ each other and which is better for logging purpose?

Comment: They mean different things. `perldoc perlvar` for more information. Use whichever one provides the information you happen to need (we can't guess what that might be).

Answer (score 5):

[`$!`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24!) is set by system calls on error. It corresponds to C's `errno` variable.

[`$@`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24@) is set by `eval EXPR` and `eval BLOCK`. It contains the caught exception.

[`$?`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24?) is set by `waitpid`, `system` and `close` (when closing a handle opened with `open '-|'` or `open '|-'`). It contains information about the terminated process.

Most modules throw exceptions on error, but some set their own error variables (e.g. DBI, Text::CSV_XS).

The appropriate variable to log will vary by what you are logging.

For example, `system` reports errors via `$?` and `$!`.

```
system(...);
die("Unable to execute child: $!\n")              if $? < 0;
die("Child killed by signal ".( $? & 0x7F )."\n") if $? & 0x7F;
die("Child exited with error ".( $? >> 8 )."\n")  if $? >> 8;
```

Answer (score 2):

They have completely different purposes.  Which you should log depends on what failed.  (And don't forget $? too.)

Read the documentation at http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Error-Variables.